# Vim exiting insert mode moves cursor to next line

Tags: vim

After entering some text at the end of the line and exiting insert mode I have the cursor moved to the beginning of the next line. I would like to prevent this.

Comment: What version of vim and what Linux distribution are you using? I haven't seen this in vim versions 7.3 and 7.4 on Ubuntu and Mac OS X, respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It suprisingly was a linefeed character (or maybe some other character) in .vimrc interpreted by vim as  command.
I have the following lines to remap mode change to `'`

```
:nnoremap ' i
:inoremap ' <esc>
```

Apparantly CR somehow occured to be after `<esc>`. Since there is no text after, I presumed it could be some whitespace character. All I had to do is to place the cursor after `<esc>` and delete all trailing invisible symbols. And it did the trick.